# Service layer and model associations with Domain-Driven Design

Tags: php, model, doctrine-orm, domain-driven-design, soa

I'm in the process of designing the base architecture of a web application. The project follows the **Domain-Driven Design** approach because the business model and logic is very complex.

The project also aims to be a **SOA** project (Service Oriented Architecture). So I'm learning a lot about Services and how to construct the project around it.

Following a [previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5850249/zf-doctrine-2-heavy-model-classes-or-lightweight-model-service-layer), I have a question regarding **associations in model classes**.

I understand that model classes shouldn't know and do anything related to persistence. However I have trouble deciding for situations with association between model classes.

For example:

- class `Person`
- class `Car` has one driver (for the example)

Where should the `getDriver` and `getCars` be?

1. in the model classes: `$car->getDriver()`
2. in the service layer with primitive types: `$personService->getPerson($car->getDriverId())`
3. in the service layer using OOP: `$carService->getDriver($car)`

Solution 1. seems the more natural. I'm using Doctrine 2, so the model associations are handled with DB mapping annotations. That way, the model doesn't do anything related to persistence (even though it **does** through Doctrine actually). It's my favorite solution, but then what's the point of the Service except load the list of "cars" to start with?

Solution 2. seems just stupid because it throws away OOP and the Model/Service user has to know about the Database model to fetch association (he has to know that this ID is a "Person" id). And he has to do the association himself.

Solution 3. is a bit better than solution 2, but still **where is the OOP** in that?

So, for me solution 1. is the best. But I have seen Solution 2. and Solution 3. used in real projects (sometimes mixed together), and so I have doubts.

And the question becomes more complex when there are additional parameters, for example:

```
$person->getCars($nameFilter, $maxNumberOfResults, $offset);
```

(in this case, it really looks like a SQL query/persistence query)

So, which one should be used for a **Model/Service architecture** on a project following the **Domain-Driven Design** approach? With SOA, should my model be only "dumb" data container with no logic? If so, then where is the DDD approach?

Answer (score 1):

In the context of DDD, this is a problem of deciding whether a relationship between entities is expressed via direct object association vs. repository. Both approaches can be valid and depend on the nature of the relationship. For example, in your domain, a person may have a lot of cars associated with them, and it doesn't really make sense to have a direct association to the set of cars from the person entity. Remember, the job of the entity, or more specifically the aggregate root, is to protect invariants and enforce business rules. If the set of cars associated with a person isn't required for any behavior that exists on the person class, then there is no reason to put the association on the person entity. Further more, as your example shows, the query for cars may need to be filtered. To answer your question, I would place the responsibility of representing the person-to-cars relationship in a [repository](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/123). SOA is orthogonal to DDD and is more focused on how business functionality is accessed and deployed. It is informative to consider the interplay between DDD and SOA from the perspective of [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture) also called [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/). Your domain is at the core, encapsulated by a set of application services which form an API facade around your domain. These are different from services in SOA, which are ports/adapters in the hexagonal/onion architecture and they serve ti expose these application services as SOA services.

Comment: OK first I understand I mixed SOA and application services. And it seems actually that all that question about associations rely on wether an entity is an aggregate root or not. If it is, I should use a repository. If it is a sub-entity of an aggregate, then I should use object associations. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

If your project is DDD I don't get it why you want a Model/Service architecture. IMO this creates an anemic model and everything is pretty much procedural .

Now, being DDD it means you don't care for the db. You have though (at least logically) 2 models: the domain and the persistence. The Domain model deals with the associations in the most natural way, best suitable to represent the business case. 'Has one driver' or has many it's a db centric thinking that has no place in DDD. The Persistence model handles the way the Aggregate Root will be stored in the db (here's where you define the ORM entities and their relationships et all).

About your questions, first of all it matters the context and the purpose. If it's strictly for queries (to display to a user) then a simple model can be used, no need for DDD and business rules. The controller can ask directly the specialised query repository for the data, returned as a DTO.

If you want to update the Person or a car, then in the Application Layer (I'm usually using a command based approach so in my case all these happen in a command handler, but architecturally it's still part of the Application Layer) you can retreieve the AR best suited for the task from the (domain) repository. The domain repository knows that getPerson($id) should return a domain entity as opposed to the query repository which returns a simple DTO.

```
$person=$repo->getPerson($id);
//do stuff
 $repo->save($person);
 //optionally raise event (if you're using the domain events apprach)
```

But what's tricky is to decide what is the AR in what context. A car has one driver in what context? A driver really belongs to a car? Is there the concept of the owner? You have the Person class, but a person can be the driver or the owner (or not if it's a rental company). As you see, it pretty much depends on the domain and only after you have a clear image of the domain you can start thinking about how do you store data and what object (entity) is returned by the repository.

Comment: You raise very good points. First of all, I absolutely want to avoid an "anemic model" and that's actually the root of my questioning. Is that what a Model/Service architecture has to be? I am confused: should I just throw away the Service layer to keep logic in the model? (yes, the domain model is very complex and justify DDD, the example I gave is just an very basic example).

Comment: Keep the relevant logic in the domain, it belongs there. Use domain Services for operations that are part of the domain but don't fit naturally in a domain object. Use Services in other layers for infrastructural concerns (authorization for example).

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about what goes where, consider the purpose of both the service and the model.  Services reside in the [application layer](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/serviceLayer.html) while models reside in the domain layer.  So, what does your application need to know about a `Person`?  Not much, probably.  The UI will likely send some ids to process with a requested action.

Here, the AR is a `Driver` model.  Keep in mind that services may contain other services and that Doctrine entites are `POPOs` and do not need to be [anemic](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/domainModel.html).  Also, try to decouple the development thought-processes away from the persistence.  For example, a `$driverId` does not need to be an integer, it can be any unique identifier that is relevant to the domain.

```
// DriverService
// If more parameters are needed, consider passing in a command object
public function beginTrip($driverId, $carId, $fromLocationId, $toLocationId)
{
    $driver        = $this->repository->find($driverId);
    $car           = $this->carService->getAvailableCar($carId, $driverId);
    $withItenerary = $this->locationService->buildItenerary(
        [$fromLocationId, $toLocationId]
    );

    $driver->drive($car, $withItenerary); // actual 'driving' logic goes here
    $this->eventService->publish(new BeginTripEvent($driver, $car, $withItenerary));
}
```

Comment: Note:  I know this is a necro-thread, but it hasn't been answered yet.  So, I'm posting my response in case it's helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

> OK first I understand I mixed SOA and application services.

True. You are mixing Domain Layer (DDD) methods with Domain Objects and Service Layer (SOA) methods with Data Transfer Objects in the question.

Domain Layer objects are different objects than Service Layer objects! For example, Service Layer may have a `CarDTO` object instead of `Car` object and `DriverDTO` object instead of `Driver` object.

1. `$car->getDriver()` is a perfectly correct way to access `Driver` in Domain Layer, and can also be used in a Service Layer with a restriction that wherever Service consumer requests `Car` data, Service always returns a `Car` with a `Driver`.
2. `$personService->getPerson($car->getDriverId())` is valid only in Service Layer and invalid in Domain Layer. The reason for this method is `Driver` data is too large and complex to be always returned with a `Car`. Thus Service provides a separate method to request `Driver` data.
3. `$carService->getDriver($car)` is invalid in Domain Layer and strange to see in Service Layer, because this construction means that Service consumer must send all `Car` data to the a `CarService` to get `Driver` data. It is better to send only `CarID` and maybe to a `PersonService`, not to a `CarService` (Variant 2).

A more complex example `$person->getCars($nameFilter, $maxNumberOfResults, $offset);` looks strange in Domain Layer, since it doesn't contain much Business Logic. But if changed into `$CarService->getCars($nameFilter, $maxNumberOfResults, $offset);` it becomes suitable in Service Layer for partial requests.