# Using Doctrine 2 for large data models

Tags: database, model, doctrine-orm

I have a legacy in-house human resources web app that I'd like to rebuild using more modern technologies. Doctrine 2 is looking good. But I've not been able to find articles or documentation on how best to organise the Entities for a large-ish database (120 tables). Can you help?

My main problem is the Person table (of course! it's an HR system!). It currently has 70 columns. I want to refactor that to extract several subsets into one-to-one sub tables, which will leave me with about 30 columns. There are about 50 other supporting one-to-many tables called person_address, person_medical, person_status, person_travel, person_education, person_profession etc. More will be added later.

If I put all the doctrine associations (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) in the Person entity class along with the set/get/add/remove methods for each, along with the original 30 columns and their methods, and some supporting utility functions then the Person entity is going to be 1000+ lines long and a nightmare to test.

FWIW i plan to create a PersonRepository to handle the common bulk queries, a PersonProfessionRepository for the bulk queries / reports on that sub table etc, and Person*Service s which will contain some of the more complex business logic where needed. So organising the rest of the app logic is fine: this is a question about how to correctly organise lots of sub-table Entities with Doctrine that all have relationships / associations back to one primary table. How do I avoid bloating out the Person entity class?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11249373/service-layer-and-model-associations-with-domain-driven-design is helpful for organising logic but doesn't answer the question directly. I want domain logic in the domain models. Anemic models don't sound good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Identifying types of objects

It sounds like you have a nicely normalized database and I suggest you keep it that way. Removing columns from the `people` table to create separate tables for one-to-one relations isn't going to help in performance nor maintainability.

The fact that you recognize several groups of properties in the Person entity might indicate you have found cases for a [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html). Even some of the one-to-many tables (like `person_address`) sound more like [Value Object](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html)s than [Entities](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/EvansClassification.html).

Starting with Doctrine 2.5 (which is not yet stable at the time of this writing) it will support embedding *single* Value Objects. Unfortunately we will have to wait for a future version for support of *collections* of Value objects.

Putting that aside, you can mimic embedding Value Objects, Ross Tuck has [blogged about this](http://rosstuck.com/persisting-value-objects-in-doctrine/).

#### Lasagna Code

Your plan of implementing an entity, repository, service (and maybe controller?) for Person, PersonProfession, etc sounds like a road to [Lasagna Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code#Lasagna_code).

Without extensive knowledge about your domain, I'd say you want to have an aggregate Person, of which the Person entity is the aggregate root. That aggregate needs a single repository. (But maybe I'm off here and being simplistic, as I said, I don't know your domain.)

Creating a service for Person (and other entities / value objects) indicates data-minded thinking. For services it's better to think of behavior. Think of what kind of tasks you want to perform, and group coherent sets of tasks into services. I suspect that for a HR system you'll end up with many services that evolve around your Person aggregate.

#### Is Doctrine 2 suitable?

I would say: yes. Doctrine itself has no problems with large amounts of tables and large amounts of columns. But performance highly depends on how you use it.

#### OLTP vs OLAP

For [OLTP](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html) systems an ORM can be very helpful. OLTP involves many short transactions, writing a single (or *short* list) of aggregates to the database.

For [OLAP](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html) systems an ORM is not suited. OLAP involves many complex analytical queries, usually resulting in large object-graphs. For these kind of operations, native SQL is much more convenient.

Even in case of OLAP systems Doctrine 2 can be of help:

- You can use DQL queries (in stead of native SQL) to use the power of your mapping metadata. Then use `scalar` or `array` hydration to fetch the data.
- Doctrine also support arbitrary joins, which means you can join entities that are not associated to each other according by mapping metadata.
- And you can make use of the NativeQuery object with which you can map the results to whatever you want.

I think a HR system is a perfect example of where you have both OLTP and OLAP. OLTP when it comes to adding a new Person to the system for example. OLAP when it comes to various reports and analytics.

So there's nothing wrong with using an ORM for transactional operations, while using plain SQL for analytical operations.

#### Choose wisely

I think the key is to carefully choose when to use what, on a case by case basis.

Hydrating entities is great for transactional operations. Make use of lazy loading associations which can prevent fetching data you're not going to use. But also choose to eager load certain associations (using DQL) where it makes sense.

Use `scalar` or `array` hydration when working with large data sets. Data sets usually grow where you're doing analytical operations, where you don't really need full blown entities anyway.

@Quicker makes a valid point by saying you can create specialized View objects. You can fetch only the data you need in specific cases and manually mold that data into objects. This is accompanied by his point to don't bloat the user interface with options a user with a certain role doesn't need.

A technique you might want to look into is [Command Query Responsibility Segregation](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) (CQRS).

Comment: Thanks for the great reply. I'd already read Ross Tuck's article and appreciated it: started using ValueObjects for common groups of fields (like date ranges). Your comments about data-oriented thinking and lasagne code are spot on: was slowly coming to that realisation. Too much code in too many layers to do simple jobs. CQRS would seem to add to the mess? You are right that the app is a mix of OLTP and OLAP: its helpful to have your recommendations about hydration. Will do that.

Comment: But my original question still stands: if Person is an Aggregate Root, and i have all these chunks of one-to-many data that are related back to the Person, how to I stop my Person repository / entity from becoming massively bloated?.... or am I worrying about nothing and should I just get on with it and write a couple of very fat classes, because it is a fat domain?

Comment: You should be able to thin out the `Person` entity by defining value objects, thus moving logic into those. As for the repository: There's a difference between the DDD Repository and a Doctrine repository. Ideally you have one DDD `PersonRepository` which gets a Doctrine repository injected. This way your aggregate + DDD repository is _not_ directly coupled to Doctrine.

Comment: I wouldn't call myself a DDD expert, but I guess you could eventually move to having multiple Doctrine repositories injected, as long as the all work from the aggregate-root. (For example, don't "find" a `PersonAddress`, but always a `Person` with a `PersonAddress`). Personally I tend to start simple and straightforward, just a single repository. And when coherent groups start to appear I extract them into their own classes.

Comment: Another solution might be to redefine the Domain. We're assuming Person is an aggregate and everything related to a person is in there. But I would suspect that roughly 80% of the entire Domain is in there. So maybe this isn't the correct choice. Go talk to the Domain Experts and find out if Person can be split into multiple aggregates.

Comment: lol. yes 80% of the domain is around the Person aggregate. The Read/Write model idea in CQRS will help split things out a bit. Our domain experts consider a Person to be "a thing" (everything we know about that person). So i might be stuck with a big object.

Comment: Would you use a ValueObject to contain a set of addresses? Or a set of immunusations (eg tetanus, malaria)? Both of these are valid over a date range.

Comment: Address: yes, most definitely. An address has no identifier, in stead all the properties (street, zipcode, etc) together form a unique address. And if you have 2 objects with the same properties, the can be considered equal (it's the same address). Immunisation: I'm not sure (I'm not in the medical business) but I guess yes for the same reason. Unless they have a specific identifier (like a bank account has an account-number), but I doubt that's the case.

Comment: To be precise: A single address is a Value Object, multiple addresses can be considered a Collection of Value Objects.

Comment: PS: Immunisations is not something I would think of when gathering information about a Person, and I think it's not as strongly related to a Person as his name for instance. So maybe Immunisation can form it's own aggregate? There's nothing wrong with an aggregate referring to the root of another aggregate. (But do always refer to the root, never to an entity / value object deeper in the graph.)

Comment: http://russellscottwalker.blogspot.co.nz/2013/11/entities-vs-value-objects-and-doctrine-2.html was good for ValueOjects. Our addresses are valid over a time period (move-in-date to move-out-date). They may be re-used (eg my next-of-kin address might also be my mailing address while I am away from home)

Comment: I think you can ask yourself the following question: If I change my next-of-kin address, does my mailing address (which is the same) change with it? If the answer is yes: entity, if the answer is no: value object.

Comment: And if the answer was no, but you don't want the hassle of repeatedly filling out the entire address form, you can still use value objects, and implement some logic that can "choose an existing" address which will simply copy that address.

Comment: I just realized that I said "address is mist certainly a value object" and now I'm saying it could be an entity. This shows how important it is to think about your domain. And even more how important aggregates are: You should be able to change/refine the domain (and its model) without hitting to much complication in the code. Aggregates encapsulate certain parts, which means you can change them without breaking anything outside that aggregate.

Comment: thanks for all your help: the initial bounty expired, so made a new one for you. appreciated all your advice. Steep learning curve...

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you have a fully normalized table persons and now you are asking for how to denormalize that best.

As long as you do not hit any technical constaints (such as max 64 K Byte) I find 70 columns definitly not overloaded for a persons table in a HR system. Do yourself a favour to not segment that information for following reasons:

- selects potentially become more complex
- each extract table needs (an) extra index/indeces, which increases your overall memory utilization -> this sounds to be a minor issue as disk is cheap. However keep in mind that via caching the RAM to disk space utilization ratio determines your performance to a huge extend
- changes become more complex as extra relations demand for extra care
- as any edit/update/read view can be restricted to deal with slices of your physical data from the tables only no "cosmetics" pressure arises from end user (or even admin) perspective

In summary your the table subsetting causes lots of issues and effort but does add low if not no value.

Btw. databases are optimized for data storage. Millions of rows and some dozens of columns are no brainers at that end.

Comment: I guess I wanted to avoid loading in tons of data when all I wanted was the name and email address most of the time. Doctrine recommends not partially reading Entities. Also: what would you do about the 50 or so one-to-many relationships (eg a person has many addresses, passports, medical exams, professional skills). These can't be de-normalised back into the Person table...

Comment: Well if you cannot define views for data slices maybe it is time to look for another framework. The whole philosophy of having a database in the background and then a functional server is exactly that: decoupling the persistence layer from the access layer, which implies the access layer to be able to take different views. Conceptionally you would try to avoid to create a mega view with all 1:n relations in. You have multiple views which serve specific purposes - each one sliced in a sensible way. So your 1000+ rows per person view obviously tries to solve to many issues all at once.

Comment: hmmm... i'm obviously not understanding something. Can we try a concrete example. My HR system has a CRUD page for a person's addresses: most have 5 or 6 addresses listed: home, office, next of kin, support contact etc. It has another CRUD page for their education / qualifications which may have nothing or may have 10 records. There are another 30 or so similar collections of data that belong to the person but are unrelated to each other. So how would I structure the access layer to support this? Does it make sense to define the Person as the Aggregate Root?

Comment: Actually I do not know your audience. However in other occasions there are different roles for different tasks in similar setups. Usually people get overwhelmed with overloaded pages and that is where you would serve a specific page for each role/task. Maybe all need contacts in a specific situations - so you have a page contacts. A sub set of people of people need to now the persons salary and their tax rate. And a third group is better solved with seeing the address together with salary on a page.

Comment: Optimization into the direction of usability is not asking about the technical optimimum but about the demands of your target group(s). I guess, this is not what can be answered here. However most the projects I am aware of quickly turn into a technical demand: decouple your physical data structure from your logical access structure. If Doctrine 2 cannot deliver this, change before it is too late.